# Populate TreeView from listbox without using SelectedNode C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, treeview

I need to populate a TreeView without using SelectedNode property.
This TreeView must contain the items (in most cases - strings) that are in a listbox. These items should be sorted like in a simple binary tree. The root node is the first item.  If some of the items is repeated, the count of this item should be increased and the output should be like that ->

-- item 2
| -- private
| - apple

or something like that. In this example, **item** is the root, **apple** should be the left child and **private** - the right.

I found a possible solution [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/447349/Populate-TreeView-from-Simple-list) but i have no idea how to do the whole thing :/

Here is my code:

```
public void populateBaseNodes()
{
        int i;
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        treeView1.BeginUpdate();

        for (i = 0; i < L.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (L[i].level == 0)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(L[i].NodeText, L[i].NodeText);
                treeView1.Nodes[treeView1.Nodes.Count - 1].Tag = L[i];
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < treeView1.Nodes.Count; i++)
            populateChilds(treeView1.Nodes[i]);

        treeView1.EndUpdate();
        treeView1.Refresh();
    }

    public void populateChilds(TreeNode parentNode)
    {
        kData parentRed = (kData)parentNode.Tag;

        for (int i = parentRed.index + 1; i < L.Count; i++)
        {
            if (L[i].level == (parentRed.level + 1))
            {
                parentNode.Nodes.Add(L[i].NodeText, L[i].NodeText);
                parentNode.Nodes[parentNode.Nodes.Count - 1].Tag = L[i];
                populateChilds(parentNode.Nodes[parentNode.Nodes.Count - 1]);
            }
            if (L[i].level <= parentRed.level) break;
        }
    }
```

And this is my code for the button that will populate the treeview ->

```
        string line;
        L = new List<kData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            line = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
            L.Add(new kData());
            L[i].index = i;
            L[i].level = i;
            ind = line.IndexOf(':');
            L[i].NodeText = line.Substring(0, ind);
        }

        populateBaseNodes();
```

This is the **kData** class ->

```
public class kData
    {   
        public int level;
        public int index;
        public string NodeText;
    };
    List<kData> L;
```

I will appreciate any kind of help :)

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code? Any error?

Comment: No, it hasn't. But the output should be a liitle different than the example from the posted link.